# Subset dataframe by an unusual relation between columns

Tags: r

I want to subset a dataframe which has an ID column (`v1`, all unique) and a "linked" ID column (`v2`). The expectation of `v2` is that it may contain `NA`s, but where it does, the corresponsing element of `v1` does not appear elsewhere in `v2`. Also, it is expected that the relation between the columns is symmetric: where there is an entry, x, in `v2` the `v1` entry of that row, y, is mirrored in another row where `v1` has x and `v2` has y. The last criteria is that the relation is not reflexive: ie x!=y.

I want to subset the dataframe to the elements which don't fit the expected criteria.

Here is some sample data to illustrate:

```
set.seed(1)
dfr <- data.frame(v1=letters,v2=rev(letters))
dfr[sample(26,10),2]<-NA
dfr[sample(26,5),2]<-sample(letters,5)


dfr
   v1   v2
1   a    z
2   b <NA>
3   c    x
4   d    w
5   e <NA>
6   f    u
7   g <NA>
8   h    s
9   i    i
10  j <NA>
11  k    p
12  l <NA>
13  m    f
14  n <NA>
15  o    l
16  p    k
17  q    j
18  r    e
19  s <NA>
20  t    g
21  u <NA>
22  v    e
23  w <NA>
24  x    q
25  y    x
26  z    a
```

So rows 1, 2, 11, 14, 16, and 26 all meet the criteria, and I want to identify the rest.

I have attempted some solutions using `match`, but the `NA`s are causing problems. It also probably relies on the fact that in this case `v2` is based on `rev(v1)`, whereas a more general solution can't make that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand, here is an example:

```
> subset(dfr, (is.na(v2) & !(v1%in%dfr$v2)) | !is.na(v2) & paste(v1, v2) %in% paste(dfr$v2, dfr$v1))
   v1   v2
1   a    z
2   b <NA>
9   i    i
11  k    p
14  n <NA>
16  p    k
26  z    a

# or if v1 == v2 is not included:
> subset(dfr, (is.na(v2) & !(v1%in%dfr$v2)) | !is.na(v2) & (v1 != v2 & paste(v1, v2) %in% paste(dfr$v2, dfr$v1)))
   v1   v2
1   a    z
2   b <NA>
11  k    p
14  n <NA>
16  p    k
26  z    a
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one is exactly what I want. Good call on `paste`.